# 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' in Chapter 9 of Teach Yourself Python in 24 Hours

Tags: python

I'm working my way through this book using 2.7.6 and I'm getting an error.  I've gone through this line by line to make sure there aren't any typos.  I (obviously) don't know enough about Python to even know where to start.  I'd appreciate any help I can get on this.

Here is the code:

```
def get_specials():
        monday = {'B': 'Horseradish omelet. Note: Better than it sounds.',
                  'L': 'Momma\'s Curry.  Note: Can be made spicy.',
                  'D': 'Beef brisket.  Note:Comes with au jus. That\'s pronounced "Oh jhoo", not "Ow Juice."'}

        tuesday = {'B': 'Sausage gravy over biscuits. Note: Toast can be subbed.',
                   'L': 'Grilled cheese and tomato soup. Note: We have vegan cheese.',
                   'D': 'Meatloaf. Note: Comes with catsup on the top. Not optional.'}

        wednesday = {'B': 'Horseradish omelet. Note: Better than it sounds.',
                  'L': 'Momma\'s Curry.  Note: Can be made spicy.',
                  'D': 'Beef brisket.  Note:Comes with au jus. That\'s pronounced "Oh jhoo", not "Ow Juice."'}

        thursday = {'B': 'Sausage gravy over biscuits. Note: Toast can be subbed.',
                   'L': 'Grilled cheese and tomato soup. Note: We have vegan cheese.',
                   'D': 'Meatloaf. Note: Comes with catsup on the top. Not optional.'}

        friday = {'B': 'Horseradish omelet. Note: Better than it sounds.',
                  'L': 'Momma\'s Curry.  Note: Can be made spicy.',
                  'D': 'Beef brisket.  Note:Comes with au jus. That\'s pronounced "Oh jhoo", not "Ow Juice."'}

        saturday = {'B': 'Sausage gravy over biscuits. Note: Toast can be subbed.',
                   'L': 'Grilled cheese and tomato soup. Note: We have vegan cheese.',
                   'D': 'Meatloaf. Note: Comes with catsup on the top. Not optional.'}

        sunday = {'B': 'Horseradish omelet. Note: Better than it sounds.',
                  'L': 'Momma\'s Curry.  Note: Can be made spicy.',
                  'D': 'Beef brisket.  Note:Comes with au jus. That\'s pronounced "Oh jhoo", not "Ow Juice."'}

        specials = {'M': monday,
                    'T': tuesday,
                    'W': wednesday,
                    'R': thursday,
                    'F': friday,
                    'St': saturday,
                    'Sn': sunday}

def print_special(special):
        print "The special is:"
        print special
        print "*"*15

def get_day():
        while True:
                day = raw_input("Day (M/T/W/R/F/St/Sn): ")
                if day.upper() in ['M', 'T', 'W', 'R', 'F', 'ST', 'SN']:
                        return day.upper()
                else:
                        print "I'm sorry, but {} isn't valid.".format(day)

def get_time():
        while True:
                time = raw_input("Time (B/L/D): ")
                if time.upper() in ['B', 'L', 'D']:
                        return time.upper()
                else:
                        print "I'm sorry, but {} isn't a valid time.".format(time)

def main():
        specials = get_specials()
        print "This script will tell you the specials for any day of the week, and any time."
        while True:
                day = get_day()
                special = specials[day]
                time = get_time()
                print_special(special[time])
                another = raw_input("Do you want to check another day and time? (Y/N")
                if another.lower() == 'n':
                        break

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

And the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python/9.py", line 71, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python/9.py", line 64, in main
    special = specials[day]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `get_specials` function should return the `specials` dictionary at the end:

```
def get_specials():
    # …

    specials = {'M': monday,
                'T': tuesday,
                'W': wednesday,
                'R': thursday,
                'F': friday,
                'St': saturday,
                'Sn': sunday}
    return specials
```

That way, when you do `specials = get_specials()` you actually get the contents of that dictionary. If you don’t, then calling `get_specials()` will return `None` (i.e. nothing) which of course won’t contain any information.

Comment: OMFG I am so embarrassed.  But VERY happy for this to be solved.  The funny thing is that most of my "errors" these past few days have come from my own typos.  Thanks so much for taking the time to comment on this.  I hope my public shame will teach me to do a better job of proofing.

Comment: No, don’t be embarrased! You will find that most errors are actually just simple mistakes you didn’t happen to notice. It happens to everyone and is completely normal :)

Comment: @user2378392: The bad news is, your public shame will not teach you to do better. Everyone makes these mistakes. Good programmers learn to find them, fix them and move on; bad programmers learn to blame them on colleagues; only retired programmers stop making them. The _good_ news is that, as poke says, you have nothing to be embarrassed about.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that `get_specials()` does not have a return statement. Since it is not returning anything, the line

```
specials = get_specials()
```

Assigns `specials` to be `None` so `specials[day]` is trying to look up an index in a `None`, which fails with the error that you see.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help!